# Formatting a Custom Number into a General Number

Tags: excel, vba, decimal

I have an excel file that I need to change Column E numbers from a Custom Format into a "General" Format.

The end result I'm trying to achieve is the columns two digit numbers must be changed to a decimal format (.000) but maintain general format in order to import into a custom program.

Currently I have code `Columns("E").NumberFormat = ".000,"` which works great and columns shows .010.

I tried to add a line to change the code back to "General" with code `Columns("E").NumberFormat = "General"` but it removes the .000 format and goes back to two digits.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Either you want a "General" format, or you want a custom one. That said this 3rd-party shouldn't be sensitive to value formatting. If you can, get this custom program to read cell *values* rather than their *text*: the cells' formatted value is just a *representation* of the values - code that's treating them verbatim as values, is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're tackling the problem from the wrong end. The number formatting of a cell should make absolutely no difference in how a *custom program* reads cell values... provided that it's reading the cells' **values**.

In all likelihood if it *does* make a difference, then your *custom program* is reading the `Range.Text` property, which is a *representation* of the cells' values, formatted accordingly with the cells' `NumberFormat`.

This means that *custom program* is treating everything it reads as `String`, and then parses the strings into some numeric value. This is completely backwards and rather inefficient.

Change the *custom program* to read the `Range.Value` property, which is *the actual underlying value** of the cells, not a *representation* of it.

And then you can have any number formatting you want on your worksheet, nothing is going to break - and as a bonus your *custom program* gets to read numbers *as numbers* and doesn't need to parse decimal separators and deal with the huge mess that comes with treating everything as a `String`, i.e. it works regardless of the regional settings of the machine it's running on.

The worksheet itself, and the number formats on it, aren't the problem.

<sub>**Typed* value. If a cell is formatted as currency, the value's type will be `Currency`. If it's formatted as a date, it will be a `Date`. This is typically what you would want to read it as - use `Value2` if you need the actual underlying numeric values, without any type conversion. That will give you e.g. `43131` for today's date.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that what you're  attempting is possible. The difference between the two formats is exactly what you are describing.